# Convert NSNumber to NSString from Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Well in some point in my app i have a object with a property `NSNumber`, well i save this object using `Core Data`, in the Core Data schema it is defined as Double.

When i get this object back from core data, with value 2.4 for example, in the IOS simulator this value appears but when i run the app in my iPad the value does not appear.

this is the code:

```
label.text = [product.price stringValue];
```

Anybody can help me on this?

Comment: What was `product.price` when you debugged it? What was `label`?

Comment: the    product.price was 22.6 and the    label.text was 22.6 too.

Comment: In the IOS simulator works fine but when i run in my iPad the    label.text is empty

Comment: mb CoreData on iPad is empty too?

Comment: No it is not empty, i can get my object from the CoreData and i have others properts too. I use a    NSlog and i can see it's value on the console.

Comment: how about using a proper [`NumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter), maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a try with,

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",product.price];
```

Comment: I have tried this way too, but now the result in the    label.text is (null).

Comment: Try to check the class type [product.price isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]];

Answer (score -1):

How about this

```
NSString *convertedString = [product.price stringValue];
label.text = convertedString;
```